# jdbc apache poi create xls file

Tags: java, postgresql, jdbc, apache-poi, resultset

i have written the following program to get list of tables from postgres database and write them into a xls file. i have included the Apache poi library to write xls file. the program is running with out any error, the is also created but the output is not written into the file the file is just empty. plz help me to write the resultset into the file.

```
package list;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DatabaseMetaData;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFWorkbook;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Row;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Sheet;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Workbook;

public class List 
{
 public static void main(String[] args) throws SQLException, FileNotFoundException,   IOException 
{

 Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection( "jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/db","user","pass");

  DatabaseMetaData md = con.getMetaData();
  ResultSet rs = md.getTables(null, "public", "%", null);

  try (FileOutputStream fileOut = new FileOutputStream("/home/usr/Desktop/list.xls")) 
  {

            Workbook wb = new HSSFWorkbook();
            Sheet sheet1 = wb.createSheet("Table List");
            Row row = sheet1.createRow(250);
            while (rs.next()) 
            {
    row.createCell(0).setCellValue(rs.getString(3));

            }
             wb.write(fileOut);  
             fileOut.close();

  }
  catch(SQLException e) 
   { 
       System.out.println( "could not get JDBC connection : " + e ); 
   } 

  }
  }
```

Comment: Please clarify your question. What you mean by 'is also created but the output is not written'?

Comment: Do u have values  in the result set did checked that?

Comment: yes when println is given tables names is printed, what i mean is i can get the resultset printed but unable to write the result into the file.

Comment: xls file is created in the given location, but the resultln is not written into the file.

Answer (score 1):

i have rewritten the code as below and now it works.

```
            int i = 0;
                while (rs.next()) 
            {

            Row row = sheet1.createRow(i);

            row.createCell(0).setCellValue(rs.getString(3));

            i++;
            }
             wb.write(fileOut);
```